# devise wrong token and url wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, devise-confirmable

I use devise (3.1.1) with confirmation enabled.

1st issue

`confirmation_url` is not like expected

My `/app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb` contains

```
<p><%= link_to 'confirm', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token) %></p>
```

Expected is:

`http://localhost:3000/?confirm/confirmation_token=3DXF7mw4KcJxtD698coCdH`

but I got

`?confirmation_token=3DXF7mw4KcJxtD698coCdH`

with this error

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

2nd Issue

Token does not match

```
confirmation_token.invalid
```

But I have

`config.action_controller.default_url_options = {host: 'localhost', port: 3000}`

in `test.rb` AND `development.rb`:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the token does not match but you could easily fix the first issue with the following:

```
# development.rb and test.rb
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

As for the production environment configuration, that is up to you.